# Can we have more than one trigger between two states in a State Machine?

Tags: triggers, state-machine, state-machine-workflow

I am working on implementing a state machine for a workflow management system based on the [Stateless4j API](https://github.com/oxo42/stateless4j). As per the concept of a Finite State Machine, is it possible to have more than one trigger between two states. Triggers are the conceptual entities that facilitate the transition between states in a Stateless4j based state machine. If it is possible to have more than one trigger between two states, how can we implement it in Stateless4j API?

Please share your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Even the Stateless4J [example](https://github.com/oxo42/stateless4j) has it:

```
phoneCallConfig.configure(State.Connected)
....
    .permit(Trigger.LeftMessage, State.OffHook)
    .permit(Trigger.HungUp, State.OffHook)
...
```